# Pandas dataframe with N columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need to use Python with Pandas to write a DataFrame with N columns. This is a simplified version of what I have:

```
Ind=[[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9],[10, 11, 12]]

DAT = pd.DataFrame([Ind[0],Ind[1],Ind[2],Ind[3]], index=None).T
DAT.head()
```

Out

```
    0   1   2   3
0   1   4   7   10
1   2   5   8   11
2   3   6   9   12
```

This is the result that I want, but my real `Ind` has 121 sets of points and I really don't want to write each one in the DataFrame's argument. Is there a way to write this easily? I tried using a for loop, but that didn't work out.

Comment: Why are you unpacking a list in the order it's already in? What's the issue with just using the nested list as-is? Is there something different in your actual data that would prevent this? `DAT = pd.DataFrame(Ind).T`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass the list directly:

```
data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=None).T
df.head()
```

Outputs:

```
    0   1   2
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3  10  11  12
```